# Распаралелить цикл

Tags: c++, многопоточность, openmp

Здравствуйте! Необходимо распараллелить цикл

```
For(i=2;i<N;i++)
    For(j=2;i<N;j++)
        A[i,j] =A[i-2,j] +A[i,j-2];
```

По теории массив необходимо обрабатывать либо блоками `2*2`, либо по диагонали. Ниже обработка блоками. Но распараллеливание реализовано неверно, выдает неправильные результаты.

Кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, как верно решается эта задача?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    const int N=10;
    int A[N][N];
    int main()
    {

        int i, j, n;

        srand (time(NULL));

        // Заполнение первых двух строк и столбцов массива случайными числами от 0 до 10
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                A[i][j] = (rand() % 10 + 1);
                A[j][i] = (rand() % 10 + 1);
                    //cout << setw(4) << A[i][j];
            }
            //cout << endl;
        }
        //Вывод массива
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                cout << setw(4) << A[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


        double time=omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
        {
            //#pragma omp for
            for (i = 2; i < N+N; i++) {
                j=2;
                int k=i;
    //#pragma omp parallel private(j,k)
                while(j<=i)
                {
                    if(k<N && j<N)
                    {
                        A[k][j] = A[k-2][j] + A[k][j-2];
                        cout << omp_get_thread_num();
                    }
                    --k;
                    ++j;
                }
            }

        }

        cout << "Paraller area. End" << endl;
        cout<<"time: "<<omp_get_wtime()-time<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "New array" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // Вывод на экран
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                cout << setw(4) << A[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то у вас исходными остаются первые 4 элемента, а остальные считаются в виде сумм. OpenMP я в глаза видел лет так 13 назад на лабораторках, и там для обычного распараллеливания циклов достаточно было написать, как у вас `#pragma omp parallel`, но суть была в том, что вычисления в потоках были независимы друга от друга. Тогда первый поток считал, скажем, первые 10 итераций, второй брал вторую часть и так далее. Но в вашем-то случае, последующие значения массивов зависят от предыдущих. Таким образом этот цикл не распараллелить вообще.

Comment: Я бы распараллеливал [так как на рисунке](https://image.prntscr.com/image/tF2rvXpzSDqFivN80wtQzg.png) - т.е. звёздочки это начальное что нам задано, цифры означают номер потока, всего можно сделать максимум 4 потока независимых, у них всех независимые друг от друга данные - каждый поток зависит только от предыдущих вычисленных данных самого же потока. Получается что нужно для каждого потока знать его позицию начальную а потом от неё шагать через один столбец и через одну строку. OMP я не знаю, но идея мне понятна что и как можно параллелить, я могу написать без OMP с помощью С++ потоков.

Comment: Да идея то понятна, и рисунок ваш правильный - так и пытаюсь делать. Но не могу разобраться с кодом. То ли делать какие-то переменные приватными, то ли еще что-то. Но в данный момент, код представленный в вопросе, выдает неверные значения. Вот вопрос как раз в том, как правильно использовать директивы omp в куске кода с циклом

Comment: @Артур Я пошёл изучать OMP :) Если никто меня не обгонит то напишу правильное решение или скажу где у вас ошибки.

Comment: Договорились ))

Comment: @Артур Всё, изучил OMP и запостил решение :).

Comment: @Артур Главная суть в том что я параллелю цикл по номерам потоков вместо того чтобы параллелить цикл который шагает по данным. Это намного проще и наглядней мне кажется. Дело всё в том, что я не нашёл как в OMP настолько тонко настраивать какие индексы массива каждый поток себе выбирает, если бы можно было interleaved схему сделать у for цикла OMP тогда конечно удалось бы параллелить цикл самого обхода массива. Кстати, цикл по tid можно вполне на любом числе потоков параллелить хоть на 1м хоть на 10, я просто задал максимум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучил OpenMP для решения задачи :) (поверхностно, конечно). Вот моё решение на C++, можно [запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NJxM/0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef int32_t s32;

#define MEMZERO(obj) memset(&obj, 0, sizeof(obj))
#define MEMCOPY(dst, src) memcpy(&dst, &src, min(sizeof(dst), sizeof(src)))

enum {
    c_block_size = 2,
    N = 97,
};

int main() {
    u32 a[N][N]; MEMZERO(a);

    // Initial start values.
    for (u32 i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (u32 j = 0; j < c_block_size; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = a[j][i] = i * c_block_size + j;
        }
    }

    u32 b[N][N]; MEMCOPY(b, a);

    // Parallel version.        
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(c_block_size * c_block_size)
    for (s32 tid = 0; tid < c_block_size * c_block_size; ++tid) {
        u32 i_shift = tid / c_block_size;
        u32 j_shift = tid % c_block_size;
        for (u32 i = c_block_size + i_shift; i < N; i += c_block_size) {
            for (u32 j = c_block_size + j_shift; j < N; j += c_block_size) {
                a[i][j] = a[i][j - c_block_size] + a[i - c_block_size][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Non-parallel version.
    for (u32 i = c_block_size; i < N; ++i) {
        for (u32 j = c_block_size; j < N; ++j) {
            b[i][j] = b[i - c_block_size][j] + b[i][j - c_block_size];
        }
    }
    
    // Output and check correctness.
    {
        bool is_correct = true;
        u32 shift = (N / c_block_size - 1) * c_block_size;
        for (u32 i = 0; i < c_block_size; ++i) {
            for (u32 j = 0; j < c_block_size; ++j) {
                cout << a[shift + i][shift + j] << " ";
                if (a[shift + i][shift + j] != b[shift + i][shift + j]) is_correct = false;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << (is_correct ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT") << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Замечания: я сделал обобщённую версию для любого N и для любого размера стороны квадрата c_block_size, у автора задача была для c_block_size = 2. Размер N я сделал так что можно задать не кратный c_block_size. Также я сделал проверку корректности на не-параллельной версии. Распараллеливание идёт по номеру потока, т.к. я не нашёл как в OMP задать для каждого потока точные индексы for которые только этому потоку принадлежат, т.к. для решения задачи понадобилось бы потоку давать 0й 2й 4й 6й и т.д. индексы, а OMP только похоже разбивает индексы for на интервалы. В конце я вывожу значения только последнего квадрата, т.к. он самый показательный. При вычислении массива индексы по потокам распределялись как [image: на такой картинке] (звёздочки это начальные значения, цифры это номера потоков). Цикл по tid параллелится максимальным числом потоков, но вполне можно любое число потоков задать, хоть 1.

Замерил время при N = 8192, c_block_size = 16, num_threads = 8. Получилось что параллельная версия исполняется 500мс, без распараллеливания (т.е. 1 поток) та же версия 800мс, т.е. не значительное ускорение наблюдается, наверняка тормозит уже чисто изза доступа к памяти, т.к. алгоритм не трудный по вычислениям а скорее упирается в скорость работы памяти.

Если кому нужен C++ класс который я написал для точного вычисления времени, то привожу его ниже:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow735386Extra#main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

typedef uint64_t u64;

class TimeMeasure {
public:
    TimeMeasure(string const & name) {
        name_ = name;
        start_time_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        end_time_ = start_time_;
    }

    u64 TimeElapsedNS() {
        end_time_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        u64 diff = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time_ - start_time_).count();
        return diff;
    }

    ~TimeMeasure() {
        cout << "Time elapsed for [" << name_ << "] = " << dec << TimeElapsedNS() / 1000 << " mcs." << endl;
    }
private:
    string name_;
    chrono::time_point<chrono::high_resolution_clock> start_time_, end_time_;
};

int main() {
    TimeMeasure time_measure("Main");
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Time elapsed for [Main] = 28 mcs.
```